# Expand / Collapse Swimlane (Domain Specific Language) C#

Tags: c#, dsl, dsl-tools

I have multiple swimlanes on the surface, Is it possible to have expand / collapse functionality to these swimlanes?. My swimlanes are going to contain different shapes (Image Shapes), Geometry shape etc.

I have tried the nesting of a geometry shpes but it only contains the geometry shapes not image shapes i.e. I have already created a Geometry shape with it's type as a RectangleD and by writing its partial class I have overridden the Expand() and Collapse() methods but to no avail because this particular Shape (Container) going to contain only Geometry shapes and not the Image shapes.

Now I am trying to expand / collapse the swimlanes itself. Please let me know if anyone has done this before.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set its `Width` to 0?